# Discrete wavelet transform - DWT (beginner)

Tags: wavelet, discrete-wavelet-transform

I recently stumbled upon this article: [A wavelet-based multivariate multi scale approach for forecasting](https://www.bportugal.pt/sites/default/files/anexos/papers/wp201612_0.pdf) (PDF)

In the paper they use DWT and I am having trouble understanding how to construct them. Does anyone have a guide on where to start learning wavelets and slowly move to DWT? I am a beginner in this part so I am really trying to understand from step 0. I will apply the math in python.

To summarize the paper in a nutshell they have this matrix X of features. They want to apply DWT for each of the columns "Xi" in different frequencies. Meaning that Xi => Xif. And they want to reconstruct the X using the optimal wavelet. But I think I am missing something here.

I have checked the others threads and the questions are to speicific, so let's try to answear this question so that it can become a guide for future reference.

Comment: One of the "Step O" to continuous wavelets is Fourier analysis. How familiar are you with this? Maybe starting with the discrete version would be a better start...

Comment: I have studied Fourier during schools years and I see ressemblance between the two howeved didn't have the chance to study Wavelets. However I only need discrete for the moment, as I will apply it in economic data (finite series)

Comment: Therefore, let's have answers focusing on DWT